# Remove status bar from CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

The CKEditor website is somewhat lacking; can you tell me how to remove the status bar ('body ul li ...') from CKEditor?

There is a list of HTML at the bottom of the editor - body p ul li - representing how the typed text will be generated and I want to remove this list.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
CKEDITOR.appendTo('container', {
    removePlugins: 'elementspath' 
});
```

As mentioned by Jason below, you might also want to remove the bar completely using:

```
CKEDITOR.appendTo('container', {
    removePlugins: 'elementspath',
    resize_enabled: false
});
```

Comment: Maybe I am referring to the wrong object.  The is a list of HTML items at the bottom of the editor - body p ul li - and the client does not like this display and wants it removed.

Comment: It called `elementspath`. when you do `removePlugins` with `'elementspath'` - it won't appear. How do you create your CKE instance?

Comment: WOW!  Who would have thought?

Comment: removing the bottom bar, gives an error at version 4.1 
Errore: TypeError: CKEDITOR.document.getById(...) is null

Answer (score 60):

Answer is here: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=42512&sid=5e2f0367542c8dc9468e6addb20d8d70#p42512

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
config.resize_enabled = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on the resize_enabled (removes the bar completely)